# Slow jQuery - long load times?

Tags: jquery

I am completly new to jQuery. It's possible that I missed some basic things and my code looks like piece of junk. Feel free to ignore this one if you like.

I wrote this code, but sometimes, the browser just doesn't respond to my "clics" and doesn't do anything. Then it works properly, after some time it's stuck again. 
Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#text2").hide();
$("#text3").hide();

$('#ball1').click(function() {
    $('#text2').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text3').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text1').fadeIn('slow');
    $("#arrow").animate({left:'40px'});

 $('#ball2').click(function() {
    $('#text1').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text3').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text2').fadeIn('slow');
    $("#arrow").animate({left:'400px'});

 $('#ball3').click(function() {
    $('#text2').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text1').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text3').fadeIn('slow');
    $("#arrow").animate({left:'770px'});
});
});
  });
  });
```

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) for us emulating this issue?

Comment: your other click events are being bound in the handlers.

Comment: Thank a lot for your replies! Unfortunatelly, I have no idea what you mean and how to fix that. I need further education, yes. Could you please explain it to me or rewrite the code? Again, feel free to ignore me if you like...

Answer (score 1):

I think your scope is messed up. You forget to close each function, but instead nest them all in the first. It's probably slow because you keep assigning the click events every time you click `#ball1`. Replace it with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#text2").hide();
  $("#text3").hide();

  $('#ball1').click(function() {
    $('#text2').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text3').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text1').fadeIn('slow');
    $("#arrow").animate({left:'40px'});
  });

  $('#ball2').click(function() {
    $('#text1').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text3').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text2').fadeIn('slow');
    $("#arrow").animate({left:'400px'});
  });

  $('#ball3').click(function() {
    $('#text2').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text1').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#text3').fadeIn('slow');
    $("#arrow").animate({left:'770px'});
  });

});
```

Comment: OMG, you guys are awesome! I mean, you don't how much it means to me to have this kind of support when I am starting out! Thanks, Thanks, Thanks